# Extract value on new newline for a given tag

Tags: regex, jmeter

What would be the regular expression to extract the value (12345678) associated with `serviceusername` as indicated below. The value is starting on a new line and has spaces

```
<input type="hidden" name="serviceUsername"
            value="12345678">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an HTML input, it is safer to use an XPath extractor.

Add it and use the following XPath to extract the `value` attribute value of the `input` element that has `name` attribute equal to `serviceUsername`:

```
//input[@name='serviceUsername']/@value
```

Talking about regex, `.` by default does not match newline, or linebreak symbols. So, you either have to add `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern, or use a `[\s\S]` workaround. Also note that negated character classes match linebreaks, so `"([^"]+)"` matches `"`, then captures any char but `"` (including a newline), 1 or more occurrences, up to the next `"`.

Comment: See [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) for more help on XPath extractor.

Answer (score 0):

you could use java pattern matcher for a easy solution

```
    String subjectString = "any string you want to search" ;
    String ResultString="";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("name=\"serviceUsername\" value=\"(.+?)\"", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    } 

  }
```